# How to parse GA4 BigQuery RECORD columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, struct, google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We're using a Python script to connect to BigQuery to download daily GA4 events files and upload them into a SQL Server DW.  A majority of the columns are Integer or String, which are easy to work with.  There are also 11 fields that are of type RECORD.

According to [Google documentation around RECORDS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated#sql) they are

> A RECORD can be accessed as a STRUCT type in GoogleSQL. A STRUCT is a
> container of ordered fields.A RECORD column can have REPEATED mode,
> which is represented as an array of STRUCT types. Also, a field within
> a record can be repeated, which is represented as a STRUCT that
> contains an ARRAY.

Here is a sample of the `event_params` data which has an array of STRUCT types:

```
   [{'key': 'engaged_session_event', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': 1, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}
     {'key': 'ga_session_number', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': 2, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}
     {'key': 'ga_session_id', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': 1679860220, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}
     {'key': 'session_engaged', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': 1, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}
     {'key': 'page_title', 'value': {'string_value': 'Heavy Duty Truck Parts Online, Medium Duty, Light Duty - FinditParts', 'int_value': None, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}]
```

Here is a sample of the `device` data which is a STRUCT:

```
{'category': 'mobile', 'mobile_brand_name': 'Apple', 'mobile_model_name': 'iPhone', 'mobile_marketing_name': None, 'mobile_os_hardware_model': None, 'operating_system': 'iOS', 'operating_system_version': 'iOS 14.8', 'vendor_id': None, 'advertising_id': None, 'language': 'en-us', 'is_limited_ad_tracking': 'No', 'time_zone_offset_seconds': None, 'browser': None, 'browser_version': None, 'web_info': {'browser': 'Safari', 'browser_version': '14.1.2'}}
```

Is there a SQL function that can be used to parse STRUCTS or arrays of STRUCTS?  Can this data be somehow cast as JSON in order to use the built in JSON functions to query it?

Comment: If you are using BigQuery, why have you tagged SQL server?

Comment: Have you tried searching for pre-baked solutions for GA4 BQ table flattening? It's the best practice to not touched the nested JSon, but flatten it first to then be able to easily query the data.

Comment: Hi Dale,

We're parsing the results of the BigQuery data in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`UNNEST`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#querying_nested_arrays). Example:

```sql
SELECT
  EP.key AS event_param_key,
  COUNT(*) AS occurrences
FROM
  -- Replace table name.
  `bigquery-public-data.ga4_obfuscated_sample_ecommerce.events_*`, UNNEST(event_params) AS EP
WHERE
  -- Replace date range.
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20201201' AND '20201202'
GROUP BY
  event_param_key
ORDER BY
  event_param_key ASC;
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/bigquery/basic-queries#event_parameter_list)

Also, this article has in depth information on how to use UNNEST: [How to use the UNNEST function in BigQuery to analyze event parameters in Analytics](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/using-the-unnest-function-in-bigquery-to-analyze-event-parameters-in-analytics-fb828f890b42)

Comment: Thanks Minhaz,

we've considered using the UNNEST function, but there are 102 different event_param_key values.  We thought it would be easier to parse the entire event_params field in the DW as opposed to writing a massive query that UNNESTs those 102 columns.

Comment: Unless you are trying to pivot the event_params (i.e. each event param appears as a new field/column), you dont have to write a massive query. The query in my answer should create separate rows for each event param.